# Distributional derivative of measures and Radon-Nikodym derivative.

Tags: distribution-theory, radon-nikodym

The distributional derivative of a function $f$ is the function $g$ that verifies $\int f\phi'=-\int g\phi$. In particular, if f is differentiable, the distributional derivatives is the same as the standard derivative. Now similarly, if $\mu$ is a measure, I think its distributional derivative is defined as the measure $\nu$ such that $\int \phi'd\mu = -\int \phi d\nu$. I was wondering if the distributional derivative of the measure $\mu$ had something to do with the Radon-Nykodym derivative, or if they absolutely have nothing to do with each other (exept for the word "derivative").

Answer (score 2):

For the Radon-Nikodym derivative, see e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4308427/radon-nikodym-derivative-and-derivative-of-functions-of-real-variable).

Regarding your definition of the distributional derivative: Keep in mind that the equation
\begin{equation}
\int f \phi' = - \int g \phi
\end{equation}
has to hold for **all** $\phi$ in some test function space e.g. $C^\infty_c$ or the space of Schwartz functions leading to related but different notions of **weak derivatives**.

Now, every sufficiently regular measure $\mu$ can be regarded as a distribution. Note that, e.g. measures of exponential growth are not tempered distributions such that, again, the space of test functions matters!

Regarding the derivative: Consider the Dirac measure $\delta_0$ at the origin. Its distributional derivative is the linear functional $\phi \mapsto -\phi'(0)$. Suppose that this linear functional could be represented by a measure. Then (by working out the technical details) you will find that, by the [Riesz-Markov-Kakutani representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem), the functional should extend continuously to $C_c$ (the space of continuous functions with compact support. But it is now easy to construct a sequence of $C_c^\infty$ functions $\phi_n$ converging - **in $\mathbf{C_c}$** - to a function $\phi$ that is not differentiable at the origin in such a way that $\sup_n \vert \phi_n'(0) \vert$ is unbounded. This is a contradiction!

Consequently, the distributional derivative of $\delta_0$ **cannot** be represented by a measure.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I am new to the subject so maybe my questions makes no sense, however: if instead we take the distributional derivative of a *function*, will it always be a measure?

Comment: It depends on the regularity of the function. If you look at those with **bounded variation** on $\mathbb{R}$, the first distributional derivative will be a *signed* Radon measure. On $\mathbb{R}^n$ the gradient will be a vector-valued Radon measure. Considering e.g. $x \to sin(1/x)$ (unbounded variation), its distributional derivative is not a signed measure.